# Convert String to another String

Tags: java, string, list, dictionary

I've got:

```
String s = "NyffsGeyylB";
```

I need to change it to:

```
String result = "N-Yy-Fff-Ffff-Sssss-Gggggg-Eeeeeee-Yyyyyyyy-Yyyyyyyyy-Llllllllll-Bbbbbbbbbbb";
```

Here is my code so far:

```
// I use HashMap to count elements
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    map.put(i + 1, String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
}

// Then I convert it to list
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> m : map.entrySet()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.getKey(); i++) {
        tempRes.add(m.getValue());
    }
}

// Then I capitalize first letters and add dash
ListIterator<String> iterator = tempRes.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.set(iterator.next().toLowerCase());
}

result.add(tempRes.get(0).toUpperCase());
for (int i = 1; i < tempRes.size(); i++) {
    if (tempRes.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(tempRes.get(i - 1))) {
        result.add(tempRes.get(i));
    } else {
        result.add("-");
        result.add(tempRes.get(i).toUpperCase());
    }
}

// And finally I add elements from result list to string:
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    finalResult += result.get(i);
}
```

As a result, I get:

```
"N-Yy-Fffffff-Sssss-Gggggg-Eeeeeee-Yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy-Llllllllll-Bbbbbbbbbbb"
```

But I need to get:

```
"N-Yy-Fff-Ffff-Sssss-Gggggg-Eeeeeee-Yyyyyyyy-Yyyyyyyyy-Llllllllll-Bbbbbbbbbbb";
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Don't use `map` or `tempRes`, just do it in two nested loops.

Comment: Your approach is far over the line. You can solve this task with two for-loops, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++){
      System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
          System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)));
      }
      if ( i < input.length() - 1)
        System.out.print("-");
  }
```

Comment: good and clean approach!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a convenient stream operation.

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
String result = "NyffsGeyylB"
    .chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
    .map(s -> s.repeat(index.addAndGet(1)))
    .map(s -> s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase())
    .collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
System.out.println(result);
```

1. Define an accumulator to hold the current index.
2. Get the characters as an IntStream using String.chars().
3. Convert the character to a single letter String.
4. Increase the accumulator and repeat the single letter string by the value in the accumulator.
5. Convert the first letter to upper case and rest to lower case.
6. Join with "-" and return result.

Convenience may or may not be in the eye of the reviewer.